# Source files mismatch when stepping into .NET Framework code

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-debugging, oledbconnection, pdb-files

**Motivation**

I'm trying to track down an exception thrown by .NET Framework when opening connection to Access mdb database file. I'm not opening the database connection directly but rather use one of DevExpress Xpo facilities (XpoDefault.GetDataLayer(...) to be precise) which internally attempts to create connection to provided mdb database file. That attempt fails somewhere deep in .NET Framework code and exception is thrown.

Exception has System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException type and is very vague about the problem source. Message says "Unspecified error". ErrorCode is -2147467259 (NativeCode is 0). There is to little information to find out why database connection cannot be created. I thought that maybe going deeper into .NET Framework code would reveal something important about the failure.

**Problem**

Source files mismatch when stepping into .NET Framework internals. Inconsistent execution flow.

**Description**

My application is targeting .NET Framework 4.6.1 x86 platform and built in Debug (Release does not change anything). Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 v16.6.3 is the IDE I work with. Of course I've read all I could about debugging into .NET Framework first but it did not help to solve my problem.

What I have done so far? I have successfully download DevExpres PDBs and sources. No problem with that - I can follow execution down into DevExpress internals (which IMHO confirms that overall debugging setup is rather correct). It also seems that .NET Framework PDBs are correctly loaded from Microsoft servers during debugging. I think that Visual Studio Debugging settings are also fine (as far as I'm aware).

[image]

All goes well until I need to step into OleDbConnection.cs file which gives the following message:

[image]

The problem is that I have all .NET sources available from https://referencesource.microsoft.com. All (including updates) from version 4.5.1 up to latest 4.8.

No matter which one I choose - I'm always getting same message about not matching source file version. When I ignore the message and decide to use the source file anyway, it shortly turns out that inconsistency is real. Instead of tracking the source code execution I'm stepping over comments or execution flow simply does not make sense and clearly the presented source code is not in sync with what is going on.

Ok, that's it. I could not get any farther. Am I doing something wrong? Where to look for .NET Framework sources which would match the executing modules and allow to discover origins of the exception I'm getting?

**Update @tgolisch**

Code which gives an exception:

```
Session Session;
ReflectionDictionary reflectionDictionary;
string connectionString;

...

Session = new Session(XpoDefault.GetDataLayer(connectionString, reflectionDictionary, AutoCreateOption.SchemaOnly));
```

Connection string used in XpoDefault.GetDataLayer(...) call:

```
"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Password=;User ID=Admin;Data Source=C:\\Svn\\trunk\\Apps\\bin\\Debug\\DbFile.mdb;Mode=Share Deny None;"
```

XopDefault.GetDataLayer(...) is the call which fails and throws exception.

**Update @Perry Qian-MSFT**

I did exactly what you suggested with no success. There was no improvement at all. However, I have made a fair progress after disabling optimizations of system assemblies as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sburke/how-to-disable-optimizations-when-debugging-reference-source). With optimization turned off, tracking of .NET Framework internals becomes feasible. No more random jumping or stepping over comment lines.

However, it is not a full success yet, because I'm **still getting messages about mismatch** between executing modules and the source code file versions.

I have also noticed that even though my app has .NET Framework 4.6.1 as a target it still uses version 4.8 of system modules during execution:

[image]

That suggests I should use .NET Framework 4.8 sources when stepping into framework internals. But wait - I have tried all sources I could get with the same mismatch problem.

What can also be seen is that there is more than one version of system assemblies being run with the app - 4.8.4110.0 and 4.8.3761.0, which suggests that different sources might have been used to build them.

Yet still, no matter which sources I take there is always a message about source mismatch at some point.

Considering that assembly optimization problem has been resolved, which framework sources should I use now to have them in sync with running modules?

Comment: Please post the code that you are using to connect to the MS Access DB, and the connection string (with file path and pw removed). If your connection string or conn obj is wrong, it will give all sorts of misleading errors.  Also, have you tried checking the stack of inner exceptions? Sometimes those have useful info.

Comment: @tgolisch I have updated original text with suggested information. Perhaps I should spawn another thread to handle the MS Access DB connection problem individually, since here we are rather addressing debugging issues and MS Access issue is more like a background. However, I'm glad to hear any suggestions about connection problem  too.

Comment: I noticed your path said something about "svn"  If that is the source-code-management product, it might be marking your files as "read-only". Also "/bin/debug/" folder gets wiped & rebuilt by VStudio every time you build (or sometimes when you run the prog).  Try copying your MDB file to a different folder like c:\data or c:\temp. Make sure it isn't read-only and set your connection string path accordingly. That might not be the problem, but maybe.

Answer (score 0):

> Source files mismatch when stepping into .NET Framework code

Please reconnect your DB Access database to refresh your database in case there are some build errors in the db layer.

**Besides**, please follow these suggestions to troubleshoot your strange issue:

**1)** **Tools**-->**Import and Export Settings**-->**Reset all settings**-->..**General** to reset all debugging settings.

**2)** then, close VS, delete `.vs` hidden folder under solution folder, `bin` and `obj` folder.

Comment: I have followed you suggestions but had no success. However I have made substantial progress. Have a took at an update.

Comment: One suggestion is that you can try a new net framework project in the new vs2019 and  then migrate your old project's content into the new project to test whether the issue still exists.